# Unable to add a table in the header of a batch of word documents using VBA

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am attempting to write a macro that opens up .docx files within a specific folder, deletes the contents of the header, then inserts a table into the header and finally - saves and closes the document so it can move onto the next one in sequence. Everything is working fine - except for the line where it attempts to create the table. My code is below:

```
Sub BatchAddTableToHeaders()

    Dim wrd As Word.Application
    
    Set wrd = CreateObject("word.application")
    wrd.Visible = True
    FName = Dir("C:\MyFolder\*.docx")
    
    Do While (FName <> "")
        With wrd
            ' Open the next document in the folder
            .Documents.Open ("C:\MyFolder\" & FName)
            
            ' select the header, delete it and then insert a table
            .ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View.SeekView = wdSeekPrimaryHeader
            With .Selection
                .WholeStory
                .Delete
                .Tables.Add Range:=Selection.Range, NumRows:=1, NumColumns:=3, DefaultTableBehavior:=wdWord9TableBehavior, AutoFitBehavior:=wdAutoFitFixed
            End With
            
            .ActiveDocument.Save
            .ActiveDocument.Close
            
        End With
        FName = Dir
    Loop
    Set wrd = Nothing
End Sub
```

The error that I receive is as follows:

**Run-time error '-2147023170 (800706be)':**

**Automation error**

**The remote procedure call failed.**

The strange thing is that it will happily insert a table into the header as long as I am not trying to open and run through a batch of documents. The following macro works perfectly fine:

```
Sub InsertTableIntoCurrentDocumentHeader()
    ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View.SeekView = wdSeekPrimaryHeader
    With Selection
        .WholeStory
        .Delete
        .Tables.Add Range:=Selection.Range, NumRows:=1, NumColumns:=3, DefaultTableBehavior:=wdWord9TableBehavior, AutoFitBehavior:=wdAutoFitFixed
    End With
End Sub
```

Is anyone able to provide some insight into why my 'batch header' macro is failing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example:

```
Sub BatchAddTableToHeaders()
Dim wdApp As New Word.Application, wdDoc As Word.Document, FName
FName = Dir("C:\MyFolder\*.docx")
With wdApp
  .Visible = False
  Do While (FName <> "")
    ' Open the next document in the folder
    Set wdDoc = .Documents.Open(FileName:="C:\MyFolder\" & FName, AddToRecentFiles:=False)
    With wdDoc
      With .Sections.First.Headers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range
        .Text = vbNullString
        .Tables.Add Range:=.Duplicate, NumRows:=1, NumColumns:=3, DefaultTableBehavior:=wdWord9TableBehavior, AutoFitBehavior:=wdAutoFitFixed
      End With
      .Close SaveChanges:=True
    End With
    FName = Dir
  Loop
  .Quit
End With
Set wdDoc = Nothing: Set wdApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: macropod I can't thank you enough for helping me yet again! Your macro works perfectly.

As a side question (which you don't have to answer) do you know why I couldn't get my version to work? Should I be avoiding using 'selection' wherever possible?

Comment: In general, you should avoid using Selection wherever possible; working with Range objects is way faster. Likewise, you'll see that my code avoids the inefficient 'ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View.SeekView = wdSeekPrimaryHeader'. In this particular case, your unqualified use of Selection in 'Range:=Selection.Range' means your code employs the Selection object for whatever parent application you're running the macro from. Instead you needed to use 'Range:=wrd.Selection.Range' or 'Range:=.Range'.

Comment: Very handy information - thank you very much once again.